# maximum likelihood estimate as the root of a polynomial

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I have worked out the log likelihood to be
[image: log likehood function]

The next question says
[image: root of polynomial question]

what i have tried to do is follow the normal procedure of setting the first derivative of the log-likelihood equal to zero but am struggling with where to go from there to deduce that it is a root of a polynomial.  Any hints and tips would be useful, as am revising for a stats exam

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag to this question

Answer (score 1):

If you exponentiate your formula, you get: 
$$
L(\theta;x) = \frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\theta x_i)
$$
which is a polynomial of degree $n$ w.r.t. $\theta$. I let you prove that the maximum is for the 0 of the derivative (it's pretty straighforward but there's a line to write down to be precise ;) ). But the derivative of a polynomial of degree $n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ which indeed has at most $n-1$ roots. Finding the roots is not easy though (especially if $n>6$ where you cannot have any analytical solution for the roots). But implementing a program to find the roots is pretty "easy", it's just a root retrieval algorithm.

Comment: (1) There *are* analytical solutions for the roots of higher-degree polynomials--they just don't necessarily involve repeatedly taking $n^\text{th}$ roots. (2) The real problem, when $n$ is large, concerns identifying *which* root to find. (3) Since $L$ becomes arbitrarily large for positive $\theta$ when all $x_i \gt 0$, something must be missing from your argument.

Comment: (1) Right, it's indeed a consequence of Galois theory that a polynomial of degree $\geq 5$ does not have general formula for its roots that can be explained in terms of simple operations with $n^{th}$ roots. What I meant is, forget about finding an analytical solution to your problem.
(2) It's indeed hard to deduce which one of the $n-1$ roots is the right one, it's trivial if you have a computer... is this a therotical question or something from computer science?
(3) Good point,  though this actually comes from the question itself and its $l(\theta,x)$.

Comment: With large $n$ I believe that finding the maximum is non-trivial, even with a computer. It's hard even to find all the real roots. If you have an effective algorithm in mind for finding the maximum of a very high-degree polynomial, could you provide a brief description, a reference, or even just a name?

Comment: You could use the 0 of the derivative. What is cool with polynomial is that you can find roots one by one, first you find the first root (e.g. Newton's method or any other algo - Brent...), and then you divide your polynomial P by (x-root). And you start again. The problem is that errors accumulate if I remember well but there are methods to try to stabilise it as much as possible. Then to find the exact max, you iterate over all your roots and evaluate the likelihood function for each of them and keep the argmax. It needs $n-1$ root finding and $n-1$ evaluation of the function though...

Comment: (cf. wikipedia for more info: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Finding_roots_of_polynomials) )